# Is performance better to use (multiple) conditional ternary operators than an if statement in GLSL

Tags: optimization, glsl, shader, gpgpu, gpu

I remember years ago I was told it was better in a GLSL shader to do

`a = condition ? statementX : statementY;`

over

```
if(condition) a = statementX;
else a = statementY;
```

because in the latter case, for every fragment which *didn't* satisfy the condition, execution would halt while statementX was executed for fragments which *did* satisfy the condition; and then execution on those fragments would wait until statementY is executed on the other fragments; while in the former case all statementX and statementY would be executed in parallel for corresponding fragments. (I guess it's a bit more complicated with Workgroups etc but that's the gist of it I think). In fact even for multiple statements I used to see this:

```
a0 = condition ? statementX0 : statementY0;
a1 = condition ? statementX1 : statementY1;
a2 = condition ? statementX2 : statementY2;
```

instead of

```
if(condition) {
    a0 = statementX0;
    a1 = statementX1;
    a2 = statementX1;
} else {
    a0 = statementY0;
    a1 = statementY1;
    a2 = statementY1;
}
```

Is this still the case? or have architectures or compilers improved? Is this a premature optimization not worth pursuing? Or still very relevant?
(and is it the same for different kinds of shaders? fragment, vertex, compute etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you would normally have a branch and almost surely both will lead to the same assembly.

```
8 __global__ void simpleTest(int *in, int a, int b, int *out)
9 {
10     int value = *in;
11     int p = (value != 0) ? __sinf(a) : __cosf(b);
12     *out = p;
13 }   
14 
15 __global__ void simpleTest2(int *in, int a, int b, int *out)
16 {
17     int value = *in;
18     int p;
19     if (value != 0)
20     {
21         p = __sinf(a);
22     }   
23     else
24     {
25         p = __cosf(b);
26     }   
27     *out = p;
28 }
```

Here's how SASS looks for both:

```
MOV R1, c[0x0][0x44]
MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140]
MOV R3, c[0x0][0x144]
LD.E R2, [R2]
MOV R5, c[0x0][0x154]
ISETP.EQ.AND P0, PT, R2, RZ, PT
@!P0 I2F.F32.S32 R0, c[0x0] [0x148]
@P0 I2F.F32.S32 R4, c[0x0] [0x14c]
@!P0 RRO.SINCOS R0, R0
@P0 RRO.SINCOS R4, R4
@!P0 MUFU.SIN R0, R0
@P0 MUFU.COS R0, R4
MOV R4, c[0x0][0x150]
F2I.S32.F32.TRUNC R0, R0
ST.E [R4], R0
EXIT
BRA 0x98
```

The @!P0 and @P0 you see are predicates. Each thread would have its own predicate bit based on the result. Depending on the bit, as the processing unit goes through the code it will be decided whether the instruction is to be executed (could also mean, result being committed?).

Let's look at a case in which you do not have branch regardless of both cases.

```
8 __global__ void simpleTest(int *in, int a, int b, int *out)
9 {
10     int value = *in;
11     int p = (value != 0) ? a : b;
12     *out = p;
13 }
14 
15 __global__ void simpleTest2(int *in, int a, int b, int *out)
16 {
17     int value = *in;
18     int p;
19     if (value != 0)
20     {
21         p = a;
22     }
23     else
24     {
25         p = b;
26     }
27     *out = p;
28 }
```

And here's how SASS looks for both:

```
MOV R1, c[0x0][0x44]
MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140] ; load in pointer into R2
MOV R3, c[0x0][0x144]
LD.E R2, [R2] ; deref pointer
MOV R6, c[0x0][0x14c] ; load a. b is stored at c[0x0][0x148]
MOV R4, c[0x0][0x150] ; load out pointer into R4
MOV R5, c[0x0][0x154]
ICMP.EQ R0, R6, c[0x0][0x148], R2 ; Check R2 if zero and select source based on result. Result is put into R0.
ST.E [R4], R0
EXIT
BRA 0x60
```

There's no branch here. You can do can think of the result as a linear interpolation of A and B:

```
int cond = (*p != 0)
*out = (1-cond) * a + cond * b
```

Comment: The question was probably too broad - GLSL doesn't specify such things, and there were no hardware / driver specifics given - but this is a great example of a real-world implementation.

Comment: You could similarly possibly avoid the branch in GLSL using mix() and step().
At the end, it matters what the instruction set supports and how threads resolve divergent paths.